# CSS numeric expression parser and validator

Tags: php, regex

I need for my current project to parse and validate numeric expressions, similar to those used in CSS3's `:nth-child()`. Basically, the expression is `an+b`, where `a` and `b` must be integer values (both positive and negative). They can also be equal to `0`.

Some examples to make everything more clear: `2n+1`, `2n`, `4` and `n+2` should be valid. Basically, `a` and `b` are any kind of integers, signed or unsigned.

The following examples:

- `n (a=1, b=0)`
- `n+1 (a=1, b=1)`
- `1 (a=0, b=1)`
- `2n+1 (a=2, b=1)`
- `23n+45 (a=23, b=45)`
- `2n-2 (a=2, b=-2)`
- `-1 (a=0, b=-1)`
- `-2n (a=-2, b=0)`

are all valid. This should fail only when `a` or `b` is not an integer, or if some other character is present in the expression.

I would like to know how can I parse and validate these expressions; I believe a suitable solution would be REGEXes, but I have no idea how can I build one for this.

Comment: If the submitted expression matches the REGEX, it should return true and therefore pass validation. I am more interested in the REGEX itself. I am using this in PHP.

Comment: Please provide examples of something that might be close, but should not pass validation

Comment: @linkyndy, ah, sorry, I read "evaluate" where you said "validate". Never mind my comment.

Comment: What language is implementing this expression? Java? PHP? .Net? JavaScript? Also, is it undesirable or acceptable to have a `+1` result for `b`?

Comment: @CodeJockey, I am implementing this in PHP. I have provided more examples in a comment to your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** revised to allow negative numbers as specified in the question **END EDIT**

If these are valid values:

```
5n+12   3456    -5     2     123n+6  8n    13n-6    n+2
```

And these are invalid:

```
25n.1   4x+4    2n+    6N-2  8n-+5   n+-3  Rn+T     x+1
```

then this expression should validate:

```
^(-?\d+(n([+-]\d+)?)?)$
```

This expression says:

```
^           # Assert beginning of line
(\d+        # Match one or more digits
  (n        #   TRY to Match a literal n character
    (\+\d+  #     TRY to match a literal plus character followed by one or more digits
    )?      #     END TRY
  )?        #   END TRY
)           # End Match
$           # Assert at end of string
```

The `TRY`s will attempt to validate, but will not mind if it is not there.

**EDIT:**

Though the above expression should validate, this expression should produce precisely the results you seek, using named capturing groups `a` and `b`, and a positive lookahead to capture only the numbers for `a` and `b` and to exclude the `+` symbol, but only capture the `-` symbol for negative numbers:

```
^(?:(?:(?P<a>-?\d*)n)?(?=[+-]?\d+|$)\+?(?P<b>-?\d+)?)$
```

Results should be as follows:

```
 source     a       b
------     ------  ------
 5n+12      5       12
 3456               3456
 2                  2
 123n+6     123     6
 8n         8           
 -5                 -5
 13n-6      13      -6
 n+2                2
 n
```

Because I am not completely sure how the `<null value or nothing>` vs `,zero length or null string>` dichotomy works in PHP and `preg_match_all`, I would recommend using this expression if you encounter any problems differentiating between the results for `n+2` and `2`:

```
^(?:(?P<n>(?P<a>-?\d*)n)?(?=[+-]?\d+|$)\+?(?P<b>-?\d+)?)$
```

This captures the entire "n" expression or nothing if there is none, for `n+2`, `2`, and `12n+2`, this produces:

```
 source    n        a       b
------     ------  ------  ------
 2                          2
 n+2       n                2
 12n+2     12n      12      2
```

Comment: `n+2` should be valid. Basically, `a` and `b` are any kind of integers, signed or unsigned. `n (a=1, b=0)`, `n+1 (a=1, b=1)`, `1 (a=0, b=1)`, `2n+1 (a=2, b=1)`, `23n+45 (a=23, b=45)`, `2n-2 (a=2, b=-2)`, `-1 (a=0, b=-1)`, `-2n (a=-2, b=0)` are all valid. This should fail only when `a` or `b` is not an integer, or if some other characters are present in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like `^(?:(?:(-?\d*)n)?([+-]\d+)?|(\d+))$`.
This will return the two numbers in the two successful capture groups.

Comment: So, this returns whether the `a` and `b` numbers are correctly formatted (being integers)? Also, the string should not include anything else but the `an+b` expression. Have you taken this into consideration in your code snippet? I am sorry, but my skills at REGEX are very low... :)

Comment: It will only match if the string is correct.  If it does match, it will return the numbers as capture groups.  You should learn regexes.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I know, I should learn them.

Comment: this captures the second number into one of two capture groups (either the second or the third) and does capture a `+` - no way to know if your language can handle parsing strings with leading `+`'s, but you could trim that. Otherwise, it's valid! `^(?:(?:(-?\d+)n)?([+-]?\d+)?)$` captures into 2 groups

Comment: @SLaks, your proposed solution also matches an empty string: I don't think that is correct.